# Coldfusion CFC Mapping to external directories with CFCs that reference other folders

Tags: coldfusion, path, mapping, components, cfc

I've done some poking around and trial and error but I'm not coming up for a solution to this problem I have.

I have a folder structure like this (example)

- Application.cfc
- Objects\

  - Object.cfc
- Utilities\

  - Util.cfc
- API\

  - Resources\

    - index.cfm
  - Application.cfc

I have one site that points to the API folder (http://api.site.com) and another that points to the overall root (http://site.com)

From Api\Resource\index.cfm. I'm trying to createObject() on Objects\Object.cfc. I set up a mapping, either in CF Admin, or API\Application.cfc with this.mappings["/SiteRoot"] = "C:\wwwroot". Inside the index.cfm I do createObject("component","SiteRoot.Objects.Object"). This correctly access the Object.cfc.

The issue I'm having is that it fails because Object.cfc instantiates the Utilities\Util.cfc just by createObject("component","Utilities.Util"). The error is that Utilities.Util cannot be found.

There are other files in the very bottom root that can obviously call Object.cfc with no problems since it just goes into the Utilities folder naturally.

Any suggestions Or do I really need to just break the API Folder out of this root entirely?

Thanks!

*UPDATE*
It's not letting me answer my own question just yet but I wanted to post here before others chimed in.

Despite reiniting the application and restarting the application server, once or twice it wasn't working. Then suddenly, it just went and worked as I would have expected. Object.cfc could find Util.cfc correctly based on it's relative path.

I gave upvotes to those who responded as they were perfectly viable alternatives and solutions and would have gone with one of them had this not just started working. Demons, I tell you. Demons.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think I would change your second create object call (the utilities one) to createObject("SiteRoot.Utilities.Util") ? Making sure that one mapping "governs" the starting point for all the objects no matter where instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

If you really cannot change your code then just create a ColdFusion mapping called Utilities pointed at the Utilities folder.